# Counting multiple data query for a single column

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, count

I have got a column name state(int) in which only 0 and 1 are inserted depending on the logic, I want a count query which can count how many 0 and how many 1 are there in the table in a single query like:

Select Count(state) From productDetail......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
    sum(state) countOfOnes,
    sum(decode(state, 0, 1, 0)) countOfZeros 
from
    productDetail
;
```

or

```
select
    sum(state) countOfOnes,
    count(*) - sum(state) countOfZeros 
from
    productDetail
;
```

or

```
select
    state, 
    count(*) over (partition by state order by state) countOfState
from
    productDetail
;
```

The first two examples will return one row with two columns:

```
countOfOnes  countOfZeros
=========================
154          21
```

The third example will return two rows with two columns, one row per state.

```
state        countOfState
=========================
0            21
1            154
```

Comment: countOfZeros and ones .. is it built in feauture in sql server

Comment: i thought we use As for resultning column

Comment: one more thing if i want to use both the resultning columns in asp.net as separate int, how will i do this coz the query will return a dt , should i do something like this dt.Rows[0][0] , dt.Rows[0][1]

Answer (score 1):

Another variant:

```
select 
  count(*) countOverall,
  sum(state) countOfOnes,
  count(*) - sum(state) countOfZeroes
from
  productDetail;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select count(state) from productDetail Where state = 0
select count(state) from productDetail Where state = 1
```

Comment: That's two statements... The OP asked for a single query.